# Facing difficulties while Migrating from Ant to Maven build tool

Tags: arrays, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I have an 2 working copies of Ant and Maven.

currently we are using Ant build tool with folder structure, now we are planning to change from Ant to Maven with package structure.

but here we are facing difficulties to change package names and imports every time due to continues commits to Ant related repo.

so..

**do we have any script to automatically sync to package structure from folder**

EX:
old style : Account/default package
Account is an folder in that we have default packages

New style: com.random.account
instead of folder and default package structure, we are going with packages

any automated script

Comment: Can you explain more in detail what you mean by "default package" ? Why do you need to change imports? Do you use an IDE to handle that?

Comment: I cannot really follow you. Why not open up a branch in git, change the project to Maven structure and then merge to main/master?